# Rails Integration testing with rspec and fixture_file_upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-activestorage

I recently ran into an issue with an integration test using rspec.

```rb
RSpec.describe "Images", type: :request do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create(username: "sam", password: "password")
    @tag = @user.tags.create(name: "outdoors")

    post login_path, params: { username: "sam", password: "password" }
    expect(session[:user_id]).to eql @user.id

    @file = fixture_file_upload("/dingo.jpeg", "image/jpeg")
  end

  it "can show images" do
    @image = @user.images.create(caption: "hello", image_file: @image)
    get user_image_path(@user, @image)
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

The before each creates a valid user, tag and logs the user in. Then it loads an image file.
The test it's self creates a new image for the @user and assigns it a value for caption and the loaded file for its :image_file.

The Image model uses has_one_attached :image_file to associate an uploaded image with an image record

```rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_one_attached :image_file
end
```

the controller and action as follows:

```rb
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  before_action :unauthorized_redirect
  
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @tags = @user.tags.all
    authorize @image, :show?
  end

  private

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:caption, :image_file, tag_ids: [])
  end
end
```

When I run the test I get an error:

```
Failures:

  1) Images can show images
     Failure/Error: <%= image_tag @image.image_file, class: "img-fluid show-image" %>
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/image/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_image_show_html_erb__3727703739275822003_20580'
     # <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.1/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actiontext-6.1.4.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:29:in `request'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:266:in `process_request'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:119:in `request'
     # /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.5/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/requests/images_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
     #   ./app/views/image/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_image_show_html_erb__3727703739275822003_20580'

Finished in 0.79372 seconds (files took 0.46552 seconds to load)
30 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/images_spec.rb:36 # Images can show images
```

I have debugged this issue with breakpoints everywhere and I just don't understand why it's not working in test when it works in production. I hope I've provided enough information this bug has been driving me crazy for the past two days.
Thank you!

Versions:
rails: 6.1.4.1
rspec: 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Changed one line and fixed it

```
 it "can show images" do
    @image = @user.images.create(caption: "hello", image_file: @image)
    get user_image_path(@user, @image)
    *expect(response).to be_success ----REMOVE*
    expect(response.successful?).to eql true
  end
```